# Boost::Asio async chat client stops communicating with server

Tags: c++, multithreading, boost-asio

I've been trying to build a messaging application using Boost::asio and for some reason my modified version of chat_client does not recieve any messages. I first thought the `io_context` running out of handlers but that was not the case. Weirdly, if I eliminate controller.cpp and create a chat_client object in main my problems are solved.

chat_client.cpp(modified from examples)I've hard coded IP of my server and port for testing

```
#include <string.h>
#include <string>

#include "chat_client.h"

using asio::ip::tcp;

typedef std::deque<chat_message> chat_message_queue;

chat_client::chat_client(std::string ip, std::string port)
    : socket_(io_context_)
{
    tcp::resolver resolver(io_context_);
    endpoints = resolver.resolve(ip, port);

    do_connect(endpoints);
    t = new std::thread([this](){ io_context_.run(); });
}

chat_client::~chat_client()
{
    t->join();
}
void chat_client::write(const chat_message& msg)
{
    asio::post(io_context_,
        [this, msg]()
        {
            bool write_in_progress = !write_msgs_.empty();
            write_msgs_.push_back(msg);
            if (!write_in_progress)
            {
                do_write();
            }
        });
}

void chat_client::close()
{
    asio::post(io_context_, [this]() { socket_.close(); });
}


void chat_client::do_connect(const tcp::resolver::results_type& endpoints)
{
    asio::async_connect(socket_, endpoints,
        [this](std::error_code ec, tcp::endpoint)
        {
            if (!ec)
            {
            do_read_header();
            }
        });
}

void chat_client::do_read_header()
{
    asio::async_read(socket_,
        asio::buffer(read_msg_.data(), chat_message::header_length),
        [this](std::error_code ec, std::size_t /*length*/)
        {
            if (!ec && read_msg_.decode_header())
            {
                do_read_body();
            }
            else
            {
                socket_.close();
            }
        });
}

void chat_client::do_read_body()
{
    asio::async_read(socket_,
        asio::buffer(read_msg_.body(), read_msg_.body_length()),
        [this](std::error_code ec, std::size_t /*length*/)
        {
            if (!ec)
            {
                std::cout.write(read_msg_.body(), read_msg_.body_length());
                std::cout << "\n";  

                do_read_header();
            }
            else
            {
                socket_.close();
            }
        });
}

void chat_client::do_write()
{
    asio::async_write(socket_,
        asio::buffer(write_msgs_.front().data(),
            write_msgs_.front().length()),
        [this](std::error_code ec, std::size_t /*length*/)
        {
            if (!ec)
            {
                write_msgs_.pop_front();
                if (!write_msgs_.empty())
                {
                    do_write();
                }
            }
            else
            {
                socket_.close();
            }
        });
}
```

controller.cpp

```
#include <stdexcept>
#include "controller.h"

//#include "chat_client.h" inside controller.h

/*Constructor*/
Controller::Controller() {}

void Controller::execute_cmd(int cmd)
{
    switch(cmd)
    {
        case 1: //Create chat_client
        {
            try
            {
                c = new chat_client("192.168.0.11", "5000");

                chat_message msg;
                msg.body_length(5);
                std::memcpy(msg.body(), "test", msg.body_length());
                msg.encode_header();

                c->write(msg);
            }
            catch(std::runtime_error& e)
            {
                std::cerr << "Cannot create chat_client" << std::endl;
            }
        }
        case 2: //Close chat_client
        {
            c->close();
            delete c;
        }
        case 3: //TESTING
        {
            char line[chat_message::max_body_length + 1];
            while (std::cin.getline(line, chat_message::max_body_length + 1))
            {
                chat_message msg;
                msg.body_length(std::strlen(line));
                std::memcpy(msg.body(), line, msg.body_length());
                msg.encode_header();
                c->write(msg);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

main.cpp used for testing

```
#include "controller.h"

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    Controller c;
    c.execute_cmd(1); //create chat_client
    c.execute_cmd(2); //Start sending messages

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Where are `break` statements in `switch` ? For `1`, all cases are executed, so chat instance is closed immediately. Also for sending messages you should pass 3 instead of 2.

Comment: @rafix07 Yes! such a trivial mistake. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your switch  statement un execute_cmd has not break at end of case. In switch statemte if case not end with break then continué with the next sentence of next case. c.execite_cmd(1]  really execute cmd 1, 2 and 3. Remenber that read and write io are async so in cmd 2 tour close connection.